# Attempting to combine two shaders for a Unity Project - CutOut Shader and Movement Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Trying to composite both of these shaders into `"Unlit/ScreenCutoutShader"`. My attempts have not yielded any positive results, as I have been met with the error `Shader error in 'Unlit/ScreenCutoutShader': redefinition of '_MainTex' at line 70 (on metal)` at each step.

Here is the first shader which is a cutout shader:

```
    Shader "Unlit/ScreenCutoutShader"
    {
    Properties
    {
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
     }
    SubShader
     {
    Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
    Lighting Off
    Cull Back
    ZWrite On
    ZTest Less

    Fog{ Mode Off }

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            //float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            i.screenPos /= i.screenPos.w;
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, float2(i.screenPos.x, i.screenPos.y));

            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
       }
     }
   }
```

And the second shader, a simply Wavy Flag style shader applied to the same Quad as the shader above:

```
Shader "Custom/FlagWaveCG"
 {


 Properties
{
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" { }
_WaveSpeed ("Wave Speed", Range(0.0, 150.0)) = 50.0
}

SubShader
{
Pass
{
   CULL Off

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma vertex vert
  #pragma fragment frag
  #include "UnityCG.cginc"
  #include "AutoLight.cginc"

  float4 _Color;
  sampler2D _MainTex;
  float _WaveSpeed;

  // vertex input: position, normal
  struct appdata {
      float4 vertex : POSITION;
      float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
  };

  struct v2f {
      float4 pos : POSITION;
      float2 uv: TEXCOORD0;
  };

  v2f vert (appdata v) {
      v2f o;

    float sinOff=v.vertex.x+v.vertex.y+v.vertex.z;
    float t=-_Time*_WaveSpeed;
    float fx=v.texcoord.x;
    float fy=v.texcoord.x*v.texcoord.y;

    v.vertex.x+=sin(t*1.45+sinOff)*fx*0.5;
    v.vertex.y=sin(t*3.12+sinOff)*fx*0.5-fy*0.9;
    v.vertex.z-=sin(t*2.2+sinOff)*fx*0.2;

      o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos( v.vertex );
      o.uv = v.texcoord;

     return o;
  }

  float4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
  {
     half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
     return color;
  }

  ENDCG

  SetTexture [_MainTex] {combine texture}
      }
    }
   Fallback "VertexLit"
  }
```

And here is currently how I am trying to combine:

```
   Shader "Custom/FlagWaveCG"
 {


 Properties
{
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" { }
_WaveSpeed ("Wave Speed", Range(0.0, 150.0)) = 50.0
}

SubShader
{
 Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        Lighting Off
        Cull Back
        ZWrite On
        ZTest Less

        Fog{ Mode Off }

Pass
{
   CULL Off

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma vertex vert
  #pragma fragment frag
  #include "UnityCG.cginc"
  #include "AutoLight.cginc"

  float4 _Color;
  sampler2D _MainTex;
  float _WaveSpeed;

  // vertex input: position, normal
  struct appdata {
      float4 vertex : POSITION;
      float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
      float2 uv : TEXCOORD1;
  };

  struct v2f {
      float4 pos : POSITION;
      float2 uv: TEXCOORD0;
      float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
      float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD2;
  };

  v2f vert (appdata v) {
      v2f o;

    float sinOff=v.vertex.x+v.vertex.y+v.vertex.z;
    float t=-_Time*_WaveSpeed;
    float fx=v.texcoord.x;
    float fy=v.texcoord.x*v.texcoord.y;

    v.vertex.x+=sin(t*1.45+sinOff)*fx*0.5;
    v.vertex.y=sin(t*3.12+sinOff)*fx*0.5-fy*0.9;
    v.vertex.z-=sin(t*2.2+sinOff)*fx*0.2;

      o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos( v.vertex );
      o.uv = v.texcoord;

       o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
       o.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
     return o;
  }

    sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.screenPos /= i.screenPos.w;
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, float2(i.screenPos.x, i.screenPos.y));

                return col;
            }

  float4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
  {
     half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
     return color;
  }

  ENDCG

  SetTexture [_MainTex] {combine texture}
      }
    }
   Fallback "VertexLit"
  }
```

the above give me the error: `Shader error in 'Custom/FlagWaveCG': redefinition of '_MainTex' at line 70 (on metal)`

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! What's your combined shader code so far? (Your error message sounds a bit like _MainTex is declared twice.)

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Hi! sorry for the delayed response. Posting above what I have so far.

Comment: As suspected, your _MainTex is declared twice -- what happens if you remove the second time you write `sampler2D _MainTex;`?